# How can I check if a class doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why this doesn't work, I'm just trying to check if `.searchBar` doesn't exist.

```
  var $school = "Washington";

  if(!$('.searchBar')){
     $('#schoolname').text($school); 
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty elementary, watson. ;)

Answer (score 26):

```
if($('.searchBar').length === 0){
```

Remember, jquery always returns a wrapped set of matching elements. The list may be zero though.

Comment: Or if you are trying to figure out if the searchbar holds a value, `$('.searchBar').val()` assuming searchBar is some sort of field.

Answer (score 12):

Use `.length` to find if it exist `if(!$('.searchBar').length){`

jQuery `$()` function always return a jQuery object even if doesn't find any element. So you need to use `.length` property of the jQuery object to find if the element actually exist.